# WP8 How to use ProgressIndicator while page loading

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to put ProgressIndicator for page loading indication in Windows Mobile 8.0, but can't manage to show progress bar at correct stage.

My code:

```
<shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
    <shell:ProgressIndicator IsIndeterminate="false"  IsVisible="True" x:Name="progres"/>
</shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
```

and in event handler of a button i put

```
private void Scalefind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        progres.IsIndeterminate = true;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Scales.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        progres.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

but indicator doesn't show up. if i comment the `progres.IsIndeterminate = false;` 
Progress bar shows, when I return back to page.

I couldn't find how to show progress bar, when i click the button until the page loads.

Thanks for your help.

Scales.xmal

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="Scale_Finder.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="Landscape"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" Unloaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Unloaded" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="110"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,8">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Name="Notes" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="D1" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D1, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Width="45" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D1Header, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
            <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="D2" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D2, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Width="45" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D2Header, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
            <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="D3" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D3, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Width="45" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D3Header, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
            <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="D4" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D4, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Width="45" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D4Header, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
            <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="D5" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D5, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Width="45" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D5Header, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
            <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="D6" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D6, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Width="45" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D6Header, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
            <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="D7" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D7, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Width="45" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.D7Header, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button x:Name="FindScalesBtn" Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.FindscalesButtonText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Click="FindScaleClick" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="18" BorderThickness="1"/>
                <Button x:Name="ClearBtn" Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ClearButtonText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Click="ClearClick" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="18" BorderThickness="1"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Ariza" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Ariza, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Width="45" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ArizaHeader, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" SelectionChanged="AccidentalsSelectionChanged">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="52"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" Name="StandartScalesViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ManipulationMode="Control">
            <StackPanel x:Name="StandartScalesStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
                <ListBox x:Name="ScaleOutput">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="Courier New"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="4" Name="CustomScalesVivewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ManipulationMode="Control">
            <StackPanel x:Name="CustomScalesStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
                <ListBox x:Name="CustomScalesOutput">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="Courier New" Foreground="Blue"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
            aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
            account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
            if the System Tray is hidden.

            Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
        <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Margin="0,-32,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: You should set the IsIndeterminate Property true in your Scales page. When the Scales page finished with loading stuff, you can set it back to false.

Comment: Hi Thanks for trick, but couldn't find how to access progres.IsIndeterminate from scales page. :(

Comment: I manage to call it but din't help. my code to call from other page is:

Comment: public static void SetProgressIndicator(bool isVisible)
        {

            SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = isVisible;
            SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = isVisible;
            
        }

Comment: do you just want to show it whilst the navigation process? For what process do you want to show it?
I need some background information^^

Comment: When i click the button, it takes arround 3 seconds to load the scales.xaml page, when i ask friends to test the program, after they hit the button they fell that nothing happens, and they click couple of times. because of this, i decide to put some indicator to show enduser that page is loading. but couldn't find any way

Comment: Can you post the code of the scales.xaml?

Comment: Please the code-behind also :)

Comment: Hi, i prefer not to give all my source code here. but what i do is simply while loading the page populate all the listpickers just by assigning string array to its itemssource. nothing else done for page load.

Comment: Do you load the items from a server?

Comment: No, nothing from server, all local, and the string is as follows. public String[] ScaleSharp = { "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" };

Comment: maybe you should bind the whole list to it. but not as a string array. you should use a ObservableCollection<String> instead.

Comment: I will check that option, don't know much about it, do you know the application Calculator2, http://goo.gl/o5yGcu in this application when you go to application menu, and sellect one calculator type, first it loads a splashscreen with progress indicator, then it loads the selected calculator. this is what i want to do, i can add also splash screen if it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on Nokia Developer site, which is working exactly as i needed.

[Custom splash screen with progress bar for Windows Phone applications](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Custom_splash_screen_with_progress_bar_for_Windows_Phone_applications)